# Where do I find how much XP is required to level up?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, experience-points, character-advancement

I was looking through the Dungeon Master's Guide and I'm having trouble finding a table on how much XP is required for the player characters to level up. Which page is it on, or is it in one of the other books?

Comment: Just a note for answerers, please give a page reference as the XP chart is one of those firmly "do not reproduce" tables.

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton Does that apply to posting the formula to create the table too?

Comment: @Rawling: I believe no one can hold a copiright on a mathematical formula!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The info you require are on page 22 of the *Player's Handbook*.

In 3.5 (and I think in other editions as well), info is seperated in the books by the person they refer to: for example, the experience points required to level up, is information that the players need and not the DM, that is why it is referenced in the *Player's Handbook*.

This info is not Open Game Content and is therefore not published in the SRD.

Comment: No please, if you want any other help expand your question and I will try to help as much as I can. The massive information included in the 3 basic books can be an overburden most of the time for new players :)

Comment: When playing 3.5, my own group created a "quick reference" print out of all the important charts from the Player's Handbook and DMG.  It was 3 pages, double sided.  They made it so hard to find anything in that edition.

Comment: @Drunken_Guy nope you answered exactly what I was hoping for

Comment: @BBlake we use post-it on the books, to mark significant pages and make it easier to find them!

Comment: @BBlake  Such a quick reference is also included in the Deluxe Character Sheets publication.  :)

Answer (score 12):

[As @Drunken_Guy already pointed out](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/46359/where-do-i-find-how-much-xp-is-required-to-level-up/46361#46361), the table you are looking for is on page 22 of the *Player’s Handbook*, however I usually found more useful to simply apply the formula:

$$ XP_{level}(x) = x \times \left(x - 1\right) \times 500\text { XP} $$

For example, if you need to now the exp needed for 3rd level then

\begin{align}
XP_{level}(3) &= 3 \times \left(3 - 1\right) \times 500\text{ XP} \\
&= 3 \times 2 \times 500\text{ XP} \\
&= 3\,000\text{ XP} \\
\end{align}

or another example, for 9th level,

\begin{align}
XP_{level}(9) &= 9 \times \left(9 - 1\right) \times 500\text{ XP} \\
&= 9 \times 8 \times 500\text{ XP} \\
&= 36\,000\text{ XP} \\
\end{align}

This formula works because leveling from \$x\$ to \$x + 1\$ requires another \$x \times 1\,000\text{ XP}\$, so 1st to 2nd requires \$1\,000\text{ XP}\$, from 2nd to 3rd requires another \$2\,000\text{ XP}\$ (for \$3\,000\text{ XP}\$ total), and so on. And thanks to the well-known formula (often attributed to Gauss; see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)) for adding up a sequence of numbers, we know that the sum of numbers from 1 to whatever level \$x\$ you want, that is, \$\sum_{i = 1}^x i\$, is given by

$$ \sum_{i = 1}^x i = \frac{x \left(x+1\right)}{2} $$

Accounting for the “off-by-one” error caused by 1st level starting at 0 XP, and multiplying that by the \$1\,000\text{ XP}\$ factor yields this formula.

Comment: Actually I figured it out through trial-and-error, it seemed to me the progression had some mathematical rule behind, so I tried a little until I found it! I must say, I tried the same for D&D 5E, but with no avail...

Comment: I also think that you can get the value required for next level by adding the level you leave behind * 1000 xp. Example: First level: 1000 xp, Second Level: 3000 xp(3000 - 1000 = 2000 = (level 2 *1000) etc.

Comment: @Drunken_Guy yep, that works too, but with the formula you do not need to know the previous experience level.

Comment: Yep, I agree! your formula rules, but I really like to de-code the math behind standarized tables in 3.5 :)

Comment: @Drunken_Guy: Actually, your relation is what gives the starting point. The amount of XP to "upgrade" is an [Arithmetic Progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) (`a(n) = n * 1000` to go from level `n` to level `n+1`), and thus the total sum of XP to reach a given level is computed using the Arithmetic Sum formula: `n * (a(1) + a(n)) / 2` => `n (1000 + n*1000) / 2` => `n * (1 + n) * 500`

Comment: Prettied up the formulas, and added a bit about how you might derive this formula (as opposed to trial-and-error). Feel free to remove that last bit if you like; it’s a little much for an edit, but I thought it might be useful.